# how to debug Spring MVC application on Spring Source Tool Suite

Tags: spring-mvc

### Debugging in Spring Source Tool Suite

Hi, i am using Spring Source Tool Suite for Spring MVC development. I have set breakpoints in controller to debug application. I am run my web application with following steps-
1)Set Breakpoints by double click in the margin beside the line of code 
2)click Run > Debug As > Debug on Server

but i don't get switched to debug mode.
Please give me any suggestion to debug Spring MVC application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select
**Window-->Show View--> Servers**.
*Right Click* on **server** in the Servers panel,

Select **"Restart in Dedug"** or **Debug** option,

Add breakpoints in your code,

Then right click on application,
Select **Debug As --> Debug on Server**.

Use ***F5*** to go inside method.
Use ***F6*** to go to next Statement.

Comment: I get "Absent Line Number Information" even though compiler is enabled with line number information. Any ideas?

Comment: This posy may be use full for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes

Answer (score 3):

Addition to above answer of viraj.

You can use ***F11*** to run project in debug mode and

You can use ***F8*** to resume upto next breakpoint.

Comment: This should be an edit to the accepted answer, or a comment.