# Eclipse - Spring Tool Suite Debug As Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to debug a Spring Boot API application in Eclipse. I have breakpoints set but none of them are hitting when running the application. After looking into it some more, it seems that I need to install Spring Tool Suite Eclipse plugin. According to this post: [How to debug a Spring Boot application in Spring Tool Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583947/how-to-debug-a-spring-boot-application-in-spring-tool-suite), there should be a Debug As > Spring Boot App option when I right-click on the project. However, I am not seeing anything like this. When I open the "Boot Dashboard", I am just taken to a webpage with release notes.

Does anybody know what I am doing incorrectly?
Thanks!

Comment: did you try to right click the main class of springboot app then click 'debug as' ?

Comment: @Leroy When I try that there is only one option for "Java Application"

Comment: The Spring Tools add some convenience features like property autocompletion but aren't required at all just to develop a Boot application. Just run it as "Java application" (assuming you're using the modern `main` style).