# How to fix breakpoint error when debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Need to debug a JAR file "ProA", so import the source code in the project,
but there is a strange error in Eclipse while trying to set a breakpoint.
Detail as below:

```
Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attributes.
Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.
```

I have try to several method to solve, but failed.

1. Under *Window > Preferences: Java > Compiler > Classfile Generation*, all options have to be to True
2. In `.settings` folder of your project, look for a file called `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`. Verify or set `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate`
3. Add the `debug=true` flag in the `build.xml`, just like this: `<javac srcdir="./src/java" destdir="./bin" debug="true">`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You seems to be doing the right configuration. Just try to clean build of your project.

Comment: Go here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes?rq=1

Comment: I have clean the project and tomcat,but the problem still exist.

Comment: I have read the address below, but not solve the prolbem,so ask again.
stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/…

Comment: I resolved this problem myself and detailed how I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46553615/1599699 It may be a duplicate JAR issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, but reading your post helped me resolve mine. I changed `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` as follow:

**BEFORE:**

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.7
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.7
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.7
```

**AFTER:**

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.7
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.7
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.7
```

Another way to modify these options within the Project> Properties> Java Compiler. So, there is no need to modify manually the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file. There you need to make sure that the *Classfile Generation* options are checked.

Answer (score 0):

In the JAR the line number attributes are missing in the compiled bytecode. With the added source code **Eclipse knows** the line numbers, **but not the Java VM** that executes the bytecode and does not see the source code.

It would be useless if Eclipse told the Java VM to stop at a specific line, because the Java VM does not know which command is in which line and so when to stop.

The only solution is to **recreate the JAR** or at least the bytecode (`.class` files) **with line information** of the class(es) where you want to set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

****Window -> Preferences -> Compiler ****
For debugging  we need producing line number in class files. 
after selecting "Add Line Number attributes to generated class files (used by debugger), rebuild the project and run your debugger to see line numbers and breakpoint, and execution pointer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDXeM.jpg)