# Unable to add breakpoint in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have same problem as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes) question.

```
 Unable to install breakpoint in sample.java due to missing line number attribute. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes. 
Reason: 
Absent line number information
```

But the interesting part is my preference has already have the setting suggested as the answer. Could anyone please tell me if we have any other working solution for that.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this with a different Eclipse? Not the best solution, I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and couldnt find a solution.

I eventualy selected "Restore Defaults" button and selected "apply" button and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set a breakpoint in the source file? Or did you open the Class file and trying to set the breakpoint? If the source file is in a different project and if you have added the compiled jar of that project in another project, you might get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if those settings are different for your project, by right-clicking it on Project Explorer and selecting *Properties*.