# JUnit Debugging - Unable to install breakpoint in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am facing a strange issue, while debugging the Unit Test, i put a break point at unit test API (Test_Computation) and another break point at the concrete class ComputationImpl::Computation() which invoked from Test API. While debugging, getting the below issue:

Unable to install breakpoint in com.lok.ComputationImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$983a053 due to missing ine number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes. Reason: Absent Line number information

But the TestClass break point is hitting, not the actual class.

I am using amazon correto 1.8, eclipse 2020 (latest).
I followed all options here, but did not help me.
[Eclipse - Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)
Can someone please help on this.

Comment: What compiled the concrete class? Was it compiled without debugging information (the equivalent of `javac`'s `-g:none`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to a wrong Mock on class. Its resolved now