# What to do when workspace build becomes stuck?

Tags: android, workspace

I am using Eclipse (Galileo) to build an android app. Stupidly, instead of letting Eclipse close normally I became impatient and forced it to close via the Windows Task Manaager.

Now, when I try to open Eclipse it builds as usual but then, at 2%, it completely stops.  It always happens at one certain project file (a project I downloaded from a book), and the console says

```
> "Native folder: C:\Users\DV9000\Android Related\Sams Teach Yourself Android Code\Chapter 18\libs"
```

Maybe it has something to do with a library?  I would be happy to delete the project but I must wait until the workspace has finished building. Argh!!!

Any help appreciated.

***Edit:  Fixed it***

I ended up deleting the files in the folder.. workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects

This was described in James Beninger's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844759/eclipse-stuck-when-building-workspace)

The post says "Use at own risk", so I was nervous as I had no idea what I was doing.  Maybe someone else knows?

Comment: I encountered the similar problem as yours before. If this is the same problem, deleting the workspace folder might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to Project->Clean and selecting the project?

Comment: Fixed it, and edited my question above.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. had to create a new workspace and import all my projects.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: do not agree. The question is "What to do when workspace build becomes stuck?" and am telling a series of steps that actually, at least in my local environment, solved the issue. You may say it's not the better approach or the neatest one, but that's other thing.