# Eclipse (BlackBerry plugin) hangs. Triggered by deleting resources during build

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I deleted some source files during a build of my BlackBerry project and the build hung. The Progress view below shows what happens. The progress indicator of the build goes forwards and back and sometimes it flashes the "*Deleting resources*" progress bar. It usually does this for a few minutes every time I build or clean the project, then it stops.

It is quite annoying and I have tried restarting eclipse with with the clean option *eclipse.exe -clean* but the problem persists. I have also unchecked the *Build Automatically* option in **Project-> Build Automatically** but with no luck.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Paul

**BlackBerry plugin for Eclipse Version 1.3.0**

[image]

Comment: Paul, sorry can't help - just to say that the BB tools on Eclipse are really brittle. Don't try to multi-task, don't expect cancel buttons to work, don't confuse the tool.... When in doubt, recreate your workspace if that's possible.

Comment: That´s a good suggestion. I made a new workspace and imported the project via Import-> General-> Existing Projects into Workspace and I have´t had the problem since. It still seems like a bug so I´m leaving the question open. Thanks

Comment: I'd also note the plugin 1.3.0 is very old now.  If at all possible, I'd update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this question, it seems to be a problem already encountered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883510/1305067) is the solution.

If the above link does not work,

The solution is to remove (copy to a safe place just in case you need to abort) the contents of the .projects folder

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects
```

This folder is found in your workspace folder inside the eclipse folder.