# eclipse adt error invoking 'android package builder' on 'google_play_services_lib'

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse is stuck at building workspace in the step invoking  'android package builder' on 'google_play_services_lib'.

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/3o4j30aun/)

can anyone help me? There´s nothing on the problems tag, by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse stuck when building workspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844759/eclipse-stuck-when-building-workspace)

Comment: You have to fix the other error first.