# Maven project stuck in "Creating Java-Simple" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ide, repository

Jr. Coder here and I cannot create a Maven project in Eclipse. I keep getting stuck on this page that says "creating java-simple: 33%" at the bottom and its literally stuck there. I need to do this so I can simply open my hw.

[Eclipse Screenshot Maven Project Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3WOo.png)

So far I've done these steps:

1. In Eclipse, create a Maven Project by selecting File, New, Other, Maven, and Maven Project, then click Next.
2. In the New Maven Project dialog box for Select Project Name and Location, check Use the Default Workspace Location and click Next.
3. In the Archetype filter box, search for org.apache.maven.archetypes. Under Artifact ID select maven-archetypequickstart, then click the Add Archetype button.
4. Type in the Archetype Group Id, Artifact Id, and the version, and click OK.
   4a. I've done this 2 ways. First I added the Archetype Group Id, Artifact Id, and the version provided to me by my institution. Which cause me to have to create my own Group Id, Artifact Id, and version in step 6. The second time I tried I added the Archetype Group Id, Artifact Id, and the version from the actual Maven repository along with the URL
5. Search for, and select the archetype that you just created; deselect 'Show the last version of Archetype only' checkbox, and select the most recent non-beta version. Click Next.
6. Add the Group Id, Artifact Id, and project name value for the archetype and click Finish to create the Maven Dropwizard project.
   6a. When I used the information from the Maven repository in Step 4, when I got here (Step 6) the Group Id, Artifact Id, and version were pre-filled and all I had to do was create a name.

It's after this I get the screen that you see in the picture I've included where it's just stuck at creating the project "33%". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844759/eclipse-stuck-when-building-workspace

Comment: Check the Console - maven may have prompted you to confirm something